how to use angular-server-side-pagination-with-dynamic-table-component
Please check my code below. Here I am trying to implement the angular material table for pagination at server side but when the user clicks on next page index, the functionality does not work and data is not updated. In the code I am using dynamic table to implement the pagination functioinality.

parent component
add-disabilities.html
<app-dynamic-mat-table [workList]="workList" [columns]="columns" [title]="title" 
            (openModal)="openModal(content,'Add')"
            (refreshList)="refreshList()"           
             (getTableData)="handlePageChange($event)"
            [permission]="permission"></app-dynamic-mat-table>
add-disabilities.ts
private getAllDisabilities(pageNo=this.pageNo,pageSize=this.pageSize) {
    try {
      console.log(pageNo,pageSize);
      
      this.flg = false
      const param = {}
      this.subs.sink =  this._generic.getMethodWithToken(`${genericApiUrl.getAllDisabilities}?pageNo=${pageNo}&pageSize=${pageSize} `, param)
        .subscribe((response: any) => {
          console.log(response)
          if (response != '') {
            this.flg = true;
            this.workList = response.body?.data || [];
            this.totalData = response.body?.total || 0;  
          } else {
            this.workList = []
          }
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
 handlePageChange(event: { pageIndex: number, pageSize: number }) {
    const { pageIndex, pageSize } = event; // Destructure the event object
    console.log('Page Index:', pageIndex, 'Page Size:', pageSize);
    this.getAllDisabilities(pageIndex, pageSize);
}


child component
export class DynamicMatTableComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() title?: string;
  @Input() workList: any = [];
  @Input() columns: any = [];
  @Input() actionColumn: any = [];
  @Input() permission: any;
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any>;
  displayedColumns: string[] = [];
  @Output() openModal: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Output() refreshList: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Output() getTableData: EventEmitter<{ pageIndex: number, pageSize: number }> = new EventEmitter<{ pageIndex: number, pageSize: number }>();
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator!: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;
  @Output() pageChange = new EventEmitter<PageEvent>();

  flg?: boolean = true;
  isLoading = false;
  totalData!: number;
  pageSizes = [3, 5, 7];
  constructor(private generic: GenericService) {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>([]);
    this.paginator = {} as MatPaginator;

  }
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.displayedColumns = this.columns.map((column: any) => column.name);
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.workList);

  }
  onChangePage(event: PageEvent) {
    const pageSize = +event.pageSize; // get the pageSize
    const currentPage = +event.pageIndex + 1; // get the current page
    console.log(pageSize, currentPage);
    this.getTableData.emit({ pageIndex: pageSize, pageSize: currentPage });
  }
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.workList);
    this.displayedColumns = this.columns.map((column: any) => column.name);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.totalData = 10
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.flg = false;
    }, 500)
  }
<mat-paginator
                  #paginator
                  [length]="totalData"
                  [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizes"
                  (page)="onChangePage($event)"
                  showFirstLastButtons
                ></mat-paginator>```

i am facing issue on server side pagination 


this looks backwards: "pageIndex: pageSize, pageSize: currentPage"  Not sure why the =+ here: const pageSize = +event.pageSize; ?  And why a const is created when you can just update the state of the model?
